ALLUSERS parameter is ignored by Wix installer
I have very simple Wix installer, it extracts a installer and a script(install.cmd) to c:\Windows\temp and run the script.
If run the Wix installer, the INSTALL.log is like this:
Property(S): WixPerUserFolder = C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Apps\Remote Desktop

If run the install.cmd in command line, the INSTALL.log is like this:
Property(S): WixPerUserFolder = C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Apps\Remote Desktop

It seems that ALLUSERS parameter specified in the script is ignored by Wix installer. Any solution for this problem?
AppInstaller.wxs
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
   <Product Id='*' UpgradeCode="3508345-7155-452D-879E-7AC8592FC9B6" 
        Name='AppInstaller' Language='1033' Version='1.0.0.0' 
        Manufacturer='ABC'> 
    
    <Package Description='AppInstaller script' InstallerVersion='200' InstallScope="perMachine" Compressed='yes' />
    <Property Id="AllUSERS" Value="1"/>

    <Media Id='1' Cabinet='setup.cab' EmbedCab='yes' />

    <!-- Package components: define which files to be included in self-extracting package. -->
    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
        <Directory Id="WindowsFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Temp">
                <Component Id='AppInstallerComponent' DiskId='1' Guid=''>
                    <File Id="File0" Name="RemoteDesktop_1.2.5255.0_x64.msi" Source="Files\RemoteDesktop_1.2.5255.0_x64.msi" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>


        <Directory Id="TempFolder">
            <Directory Id="tmpdir" Name="~_tmpdir">
                <Component Id='AppInstallScript' DiskId='1' Guid=''>
                    <File Id="File100" Name="install.cmd" Source="Files\install.cmd" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>  
        </Directory>  

        
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id='InstallFeature' Title='Install Feature' Level='1'>
        <ComponentRef Id='AppInstallerComponent' />
        <ComponentRef Id='AppInstallerScript' />
    </Feature>

    <!-- Run Action: define which file to run after the package is extracted -->
    <CustomAction Id="RunWrapExe" Return="asyncNoWait" Execute="deferred" 
                  FileKey="File100" ExeCommand=""
                  HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="RunWrapExe" 
                After="InstallFiles">NOT REMOVE~="ALL"</Custom>
        <PublishComponents Suppress="yes" />
        <PublishFeatures Suppress="yes" />
        <PublishProduct Suppress="yes" />
        <RegisterProduct Suppress="yes" />
        <RegisterUser Suppress="yes" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

   </Product>
</Wix>

install.cmd
REM The following is required in all INSTALL.CMD files
Call c:\system.sav\util\SetVariables.cmd
Set block=%~dp0
Set TMP=C:\Windows\Temp
Set TEMP=%TMP%
 
REM Install Remote Desktop & capture logs
start /wait msiexec.exe ALLUSERS=1 /i C:\Windows\Temp\RemoteDesktop_1.2.5255.0_x64.msi /l* C:\Windows\Temp\INSTALL.log /quiet /norestart

REM if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 del /F /Q C:\Windows\Temp\RemoteDesktop_1.2.5255.0_x64.msi

logs comparison:


To be able to set a property in an .msi from commandline it has to be defined as all capital letters. Setting ALLUSERS=1 in your commandline actually creates a new property ALLUSERS with value 1 instead of setting value 1 to your property AllUSERS. In the log you should be able to see that happen.
